# below python code results different output than in real maths

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below code's output different result , while in daily mathematics it results same

```
d=1.11-1.10 
e=2.11-2.10  
print('d= ', d ,'e= ' , e)
```

Comment: Floating point values are not abstract maths however.

Comment: Next time please also show the output of the program so that people don't need to guess what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

you are using floating point mathematics, which has limited accuracy. The results are expected!

If you want accurate results, you could use decimal arithmetics:

```
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal('1.11') - Decimal('1.10')
Decimal('2.11') - Decimal('2.10')
```